# rosserial arduino

Tags: arduino, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It seems like I can interface a ROS runtime graph with an arduino using rosserial. But I am not sure which Arduino to get. I wouldn't want to get an arduino that rosserial couldn't support... I am mostly worried about the memory requirements. Because running rosserial could be memory intensive in certain cases.

So my question is..should I go with the cheapest available arduino or should I go with the one that has the most RAM? My ultimate goal is to interface ROS with an arduino so that I can send and recieve signals or message between a ROS runtime graph and the arduino..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/28548/rosserial-arduino/) by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on ROS Answers with karma: 121 on 2012-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It depends on how much you want to do.

The UNO and Nano do work with rosserial and they are quite cheap.
You should get the versions with the 328 ship.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-03-01**:
Is there  a particular reason that you recommend the arduino's with the 328 chip?

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-03-01**:
The 168 have less memory. Usually all new ones have the 328.

**Comment by [cassander](https://answers.ros.org/users/1815/cassander/) on 2012-03-01**:
thanks for the clarification. I'll go with the UNO R3 > )